# React: Preventing Navbar Rerenders with Layout Routes in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm encountering unexpected navbar re-renders despite setting up layout routes in my React application.

Here's how my setup looks:

App.tsx

```
const PageLayout = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <NextUIProvider navigate={navigate}>
      <div className="flex flex-col h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <Header />
        <main className="flex flex-grow">
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="flex-grow relative ">
            <Outlet />
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </NextUIProvider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Build />} />
        <Route path="/entity" element={<Entity />} />
        <Route path="/intent" element={<Intent />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Sidebar.tsx

```
  <Tabs
          ...      
          onSelectionChange={(newValue) => {
          if (newValue === "manage") {
            Navigate("/intent");
          } else {
            Navigate("/");
          }

          //@ts-ignore
          setSelected(newValue);
        }}
      
      >
        <Tab key="build" title="Build">
          <BuildSidebarContent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab
          key="manage"
          title="Manage"
         
        >
          <ManageSidebarContent />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
```

Navbar.tsx

```
export default function Header() {
  const [searchOpen, setSearchOpen] = useState(false);

  if (searchOpen) {
    return (
      <Navbar
        isBordered
        maxWidth="full"
        className="px-4"
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <NavbarContent justify="start">
          <Tooltip content="Close">
            <Button
              onPress={() => {
                setSearchOpen(false);
              }}
              isIconOnly
              variant="faded"
              aria-label="close search"
            >
              <ArrowLeftIcon />
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
        ...navitems
               </Navbar>
    );
  } else
    return (
      <Navbar
        isBordered
        maxWidth="full"
        className="px-4 "
        style={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        <NavbarContent justify="start">
          <Tooltip content="Main menu">
            <Button isIconOnly variant="faded" aria-label="open drawer">
              <TextAlignJustifyIcon />
            </Button>
          </Tooltip>
         ...navitems
        </NavbarContent>
      </Navbar>
    );
}
```

I expect the navbar to remain static when changing tabs in the sidebar or in general when i am using the Navigate function. However, in React DevTools, I noticed the navbar re-renders with a blue color, indicating a rerender.

How can I ensure the navbar doesn't rerender ?

Comment: What navbar are you referring to? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so we can understand what your sidebar component does and when it does it? Also, is there some an issue or problem *because* React is rerendering a component? A couple general React rules are (1) don't prematurely optimize and (2) don't go out of your way to prevent component rerenders.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese, there isn't an issue per se, but I'm using the page layout to prevent common components from re-rendering. I just wanted to understand what might be causing any potential issues.

Comment: That's not the purpose of layout route components though. I don't think you have provided enough code to say why anything might be rendering more often than you are expecting or wanting.

Comment: does the provided header component help, or would you prefer if I set up a StackBlitz project? My apologies for any inconvenience; I'm relatively new to React.

Comment: I think so. So you are saying that navigating between tabs in the `Sidebar` component is making the `Header`, or more specifically the `Navbar`, component rerender? Is `Navigate` in the tabs the `navigate` function returned by the `useNavigate` hook? Yes, a ***running*** example we could inspect could be helpful. I prefer [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) but a stackblitz can work.